# PHP Variable in CURL URL

Tags: php, variables, url, curl

I have searched many previous posts here, and nothing seems to work with my issue. In a nutshell, I am looking to include a PHP variable in the following code. This code below works as it is hardcoded, but I get an error when I replace the word MAYIAHH with a variable `$hid` (which has been declared).

I have tried `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and all sorts, but nothing seems to help. Any ideas, please?

```
function send_request($xml)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
        'https://rest.reserve-online.net/availability?properties=MAYIAHH');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "uname:pass");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to concat the url string?

```
$hid = 'MAYIAHH';
$url = 'https://rest.reserve-online.net/availability?properties='.$hid;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "uname:pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried that. I have pretty much tried all variations. Including with curly brackets, single quote a dot etc